# How get param from url with "?"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I need to use url like "http://test.com/authors/carroll/books?offset=1&limit=5"

I have route like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('/authors/{authorId}/books', 'ApiController@show')->name('api.show');
});
```

How should I change it to get limit and offset?

Comment: fyi: pagination is solved for you already just see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily access query parameters in your controller method

```
public function books(Request $request) {

    $offset = $request->get('offset'); 
    $limit = $request->get('limit');

}
```